# How to execute async functions in order to fetch url from firebase storage in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

My use case is that i have a main folder with subfolder and each subfolder has two files in firebase storage. in node i want to loop over each subfolder and than get url for each file by looping. I have the code but it not working the way i want. i want to store url in mongodb in a way that each document has two file url from each subfolders in storage.

```js
  const info={}
  const Ref = ref(storage, 'main folder in firebase')
  listAll(Ref).then((res) => {
    res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
      console.log("prefix" + folderRef);
      listAll(folderRef).then((res) => {
        getDownloadURL(res.items[0])
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
            if (url.search("html") === -1) {
              info.image = `${url}`;
            } else {
              info.doc = `${url}`;
            }
            return info;
          })
          .then((info) => {
            getDownloadURL(res.items[1])
              .then((url) => {
                console.log(url);
                if (url.search("html") === -1) {
                  info.image = `${url}`;
                } else {
                  info.doc = `${url}`;
                }
                return info;
              })
              .then((info) => {
                console.log(info);
              });
          });
      });
    });
  });
```

this is the ouput i get. the image and doc object should than store in mongodb as document. but its not in right order. structure in firebase is `main folder -->template1 CV1.png test.html -->template2 CV2.png test.html -->template3 CV3.png test.html` 
but the output is weird its not showing url of files of specific subfolder in one object as you see below.

prefixgs://my-first-project.appspot.com/data/template1

prefixgs://my-first-project.appspot.com/data/template2

prefixgs://my-first-project.appspot.com/data/template3

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate1%2Fcv1.PNG
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate2%2Fcv2.PNG?
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Fcv3.PNG?
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate1%2Ftest.html?

{
image: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Fcv3.PNG?',
doc: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate1%2Ftest.html?'
}
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate2%2Ftest.html?

{
image: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Fcv3.PNG?',
doc: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate2%2Ftest.html?'
}
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Ftest.html?

{
image: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Fcv3.PNG?',
doc: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-first-project-9f749.appspot.com/o/data%2Ftemplate3%2Ftest.html?'
}

**Solution:**
I have found a solution finally for any one who wants to iterate over subfolder within folder and than iterate over the files inside inside each folder so that files of each subfolder form a document in mongodb. the listALL() and getDownloadURL are both async functions so you have to wait for each listALL and getDownloadURL using Promise.all method.

```js
listAll('main folder Reference').then((res) => {
      const folders = res.prefixes.map(('Reference of each subfolder') => listAll(folderRef));
      Promise.all(folders).then((res) => {
      // res is array of object
        const files = res.map((object) => {
        // object is object with items as property which is array
          const item = object.items.map((itemRef) => getDownloadURL(itemRef));
          Promise.all(item).then((result) => {
          // result is array of all url of files within any subfolder
            result.forEach((itemURL) => {
            // this is my use case to save files url of each subfolder inside mongodb as document
              if (itemURL.search("html") === -1) {
                info.image = itemURL;
              } else {
                info.doc = itemURL;
              }
            });
            console.log(info);
            const newList = new templates({
              ...info,
            });
            try {
              newList.save();
              console.log(info);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of output that you are looking for? What do you mean by "each document has 2 urls"?

Comment: document in mongodb should get only two url that are inside subfolder in firebase storage.

Comment: I understand, can you show us how are your files structures in Firebase storage? Also why do you have `url.search('html')` in the code, is it related?

Comment: i have edited the question. Kindly take a look. search is related in a way that image url should go in image property in info object and html file url go under doc property in info.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I meant to ask how do you decide which 2 files should go in a mongodb document? How do you decide that and where does the document ID come from hence I had asked a _screenshot_ of Firebase storage strcuture.

Comment: so if you look at first object in output. you would see that it has image url from subfolder template3 and doc url from subfolder template1. i want the image and doc in object from same subfolder like image and doc in object should be from template1

Comment: no i dont need document ID to store in mongodb. i have collection in database called template of specific schema. so when info object has two property like image and doc. i save that info object into that collection so it create a document inside with image and doc url next time it will again make a info object with other subfolder files and than save it in mongodb as new document.

Comment: @Dharmaraj. can you help i been trying but havnt got the result i wanted